# Add MapView and buttons, labels etc.. in the same window with kivy python

Tags: python, kivy, mkmapview

i've never used OOP and Kivy so I ask you here..
I'd like to insert map and buttons, labels etc... in the same screen but I really don't know how, do you have any tutorials or anything?

My current code :

main.py :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy_garden.mapview import MapView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

my.kv :

```
#:import MapView kivy.garden.mapview.MapView

MapView:

    size_hint: 0.6,0.7
    pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "top":0.8}
    lat: 46.691858
    lon: 3.048459
    zoom: 6
    on_lat:
        print("latitude : ",self.lat)
    on_lon:
        print("longitude : ",self.lon)

    MapMarkerPopup:
        lat:46
        lon:3

        
<Button>:
    font_size: 24
    color:0.5,0.2,0.3,1
    size_hint: 0.1,0.05

<FloatLayout>:
    Button:
        pos_hint: {"x":0.02, "top":1}
        text: "OK"

    Button:
        id: btn
        text: "OK 2" if btn.state == "normal" else "Appui"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.02, "top":0.9}
```

It's really simple I think but currently I don't know how to do..

Thank you !

PS: I develop this app for windows 10, 7 and xp, not for android

Comment: Have you tried just moving the `MapView:` rule in your `kv` to inside the `<FloatLayout>` rule?

Comment: I just tried it, and it works... I don't understand because two days ago I tried to do this... I probably made a mistake, so... THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!